# Codeigniter roles for admin and user

Tags: php, codeigniter

`users.php`

I have made a login form which works now and goes to `admin_view`. I do need a `user_login` for users so the user_view should be loading if the user is a `user`.

I need to something with the database first maybe a type enumeration or a boolean (value `1` for admin and `0` for user)

```
public function login() {
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'trim|required|min_length[3]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'trim|required|min_length[3]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('confirm_password', 'Confirm Password', 'trim|required|min_length[3]|matches[password]');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
        $data = array(
            'errors' => validation_errors()
            );

        $this->session->set_flashdata($data);

        redirect('home');
    } else {
        $username = $this->input->post('username');
        $password = $this->input->post('password');
        $user_id = $this->user_model->login_user($username, $password);

        if($user_id) {
            $user_data = array(
                'user_id' => $user_id,
                'username' => $username,
                'logged_in' => true
                );

            $this->session->set_userdata($user_data);
            $this->session->set_flashdata('login_success', 'You are now logged in');
            // I need to load a user_view when the user have a user role.
            $data['main_view'] = "admin_view";
            $this->load->view('layouts/main', $data);
            // redirect('home/index');

            redirect('home/index');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: How do create a user role? now I only do have an admin role.

Comment: Add table roles and add table user_role and describe many to many relationship. I know its not easy. Or just add role column to users table if user has only one type of role. It can even be varchar type/enum, whatever you want, 1-5 level of user access and so on. Or other option: use ion_auth.

Answer (score 0):

Edit following rereading of the question: If you can set an admin role you can set a user role too. It is the same methodology just with a user_role column. You can set this to be anything from 1-9 or 1-20 or 1-999 if you need it.

There are many ways to achieve this so no one way will answer your question. For instance you could set a column as you suggested in your user table to indicate if the user is an admin or not. (How this gets set to admin is a different issue but for now you can manually change it.)

Once authenticated, you could set a session variable to indicate that the user is an admin, or when logging in, return an array that contains more than the user id, but the role setting as well.

Personally I like to have at least as a minimum a user role, and admin role and a god role that I reserve for system admins. However normally roles would be set in a different table so many roles and responsibilities could be set. Even making roles editable to what they can do against certain permission settings, but that is far more complex.

When you authorize a user, ie are they logged in, you can then return not just that they are logged in but if they are an admin or not, or what level of permission they have. If they are an admin, you can add to the menus the admin navigation, or a link to an entirely separate admin section, or redirect them immediately to the admin screens. That is up to you.

In you controller posted you seem to be loading an admin view, and then redirecting them to another controller. This does not make any sense to me. It should be something like:

```
$user = $this->authentication_model->login_user($username, $password);
if ( (!empty($user)) AND (empty($user['error']))  // however your authentication works
{ 
    if ($user['is_admin'] > 0)
    {
        // is user AND is admin so deal with as you want
        // You might set session variables for instance
        // Or you might redirect to admin screens
        // Or you might redirect different admin level differently
        // Or you might just load additional menu views
    }
    else
    {
       // is user so do whatever
       // You might set a session variable
       // You might set a cookie value
       // You might redirect
    }
}
else
{
     // There was a login error message so deal with that here
}
```

Again, there are just so many different ways to do this. It might be worth taking a look at some of the existing authentication and authorization scripts already available, to use or to learn from. There is a great summary of them here but it is not exhaustive of the possibilities.

http://webeasystep.com/blog/view_article/What_is_the_best_authentication_library_for_CodeIgniter

Personally I like ION Auth, which I find easy to customize and use in any way I want, in a limited fashion or full blown usage, but that is very much a personal preference.